# Não estou sabendo onde colocar os array

Tags: javascript, array

Olá, boa tarde. Estou com uma lista de exercício para praticar mais sobre os arrays, funções e retornos e tem uma questão que não estou conseguindo como vou colocar os arrays. A questão é o seguinte:

> Desenvolva uma função chamada stringTripletGroup que recebe um parâmetro:
>
> 1. string, sendo uma string representando uma frase.
>    E deve retornar um novo array com esta frase fatiada em 3 em 3 caracteres posicionados ao longo do array. Caso a quantidade de letras da última posição seja menor que 3, deverá ser completado com espaços vazios.
>
> Exemplo:
>
> ```
> stringTripletGroup("Os três mosqueteiros");
> ```
>
> ⁠// Deve retornar:
>
> ⁠// ["Os ", "trê", "s m", "osq", "uet", "eir", "os "] e fiz assim: stringTripletGroup[]

Eu fiz assim:

```
function stringTripletGroup(frase) {
    let r = 0;
      for ( let i = 0; i <= frase.length; i++) {
      if (frase[i] == frase) {
        r++; 
      }
    }
      return r;
  }
  console.log(stringTripletGroup("Os três mosqueteiros"));
```

Está me retornado 0 ao invés de retornar como o exemplo

Comment: Parece que vc so jogou qualquer codigo como tentativa. Sua funcao nao faz sentido algum.

Answer (score -3):

Abaixo iniciei um array (`resultado`) vazio e através de um `loop for` com incrementos de 3 em 3 fui pegando 3 posições ao longo da frase. Acredito que resolva seu problema:

```js
function stringTripletGroup(frase) {
  const resultado = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < frase.length; i = i + 3) {
    resultado.push(frase.substr(i, 3).padEnd(3, ' '));
  }
  
  return resultado;
}

console.log(stringTripletGroup("Os três mosqueteiros"));
```